# merging two three dimensional arrays based on a common key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a table that is made up of multidimensional arrays of the form

```
array([id]=>([license]=>[date])) and array([id]=>([cost]=>[details]))
```

where one entry in first array has multiple entries in the second array.

Is there a way to merge the arrays based on the id in a for each loop?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a slightly more specific definition of the arrays involved then a complete answer might be forthcoming. Edit your question, DONT put that in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

there is function array_merge_recursive:

```
print_r(array_merge_recursive(
   array('id'=>array('license'=>'date')),
   array('id'=>array('cost'=>'details'))));
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [license] => date
            [cost] => details
        )

)
```